# Strange touchscreen problems on Sony Xperia Z1 Compact

Tags: hardware, touchscreen, sony-xperia

I'm having a strange touchscreen issue with an Xperia Z1 Compact. It's generally working fine with no obvious physical damage. Awhile back it was triggering random touch events. I eventually peeled off the factory-installed screen protection film and that problem went away - but there is a region of the screen that still has very strange problems: most but not all software buttons work - so typing works fine, but some buttons in the same region can't be pressed. For example, after I did a full OS-reflash, there was a welcome screen to SMS/Messaging which I couldn't dismiss. I thought perhaps messaging was crashing, but I later plugged in a mouse and was able to click on the button. Now messaging works fine. It was a large button in the same region of the screen as the keyboard (which works fine) so I don't understand why I couldn't press it.

Similarly, when I swipe, if I cross this region it is often interpreted as a button press - I suspect the swipe is "noisy" and is getting interpreted as button presses. But, as a very weird example, if I swipe left and right on the home screen in this region, the background will move but not the contents (app-icons/widgets). Normally both drag together - which is also the case if I use a mouse (this is possibly correct behavior - to alter the background region, although still odd that the mouse behaves differently). It's almost as if there are 2 different aspects to the touch-interface and one is damaged in this region.

The only setting I can find is under language inputs I can adjust pointer speed but this doesn't seem to have much effect.

Anyway, will keep using the phone for now with some frustrations but just curious if anyone has any explanation, similar problems, and possible solutions. Thanks.

Comment: Use one or more touchscreen test app if you have non-working areas or if there is a displacement between your touch on the screen and where it is detected. The latter may be a problem if you can't touch buttons that are small.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried a few apps - those that "map / repair" problem areas seem useless. I found one that leaves dots as pressed - it clearly shows a damaged horizontal region. Explains why swiping up/down is such a pain. Still find it odd that I can swipe left/right everywhere and use the keyboard which is smack in the middle of that region but often can't press fairly large buttons. Maybe some operations average the finger over a larger region and estimate location while others require an exact press. Just a guess. Looks like only solution is hardware replacement. Thanks.